# Rendering data in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, stenciljs

I have an object named `data` that contains information about `book`. The simplest thing I want to do is render the book name. I am trying like below. Not working.

```
 const data = {
       "book": {
       "id": "2d320",
       "name": "book 1",
       "Chapters": [
                {
                 "No": "1",
                 "date": "2010-04-22",
                 "plots": [
                            {
                              "name": "Hero"
                            }
                          ]
                 },
                 {
                 "No": "2",
                 "date": "2010-04-22",
                 "plots": [
                            {
                              "name": "Heroine"
                            }
                           ]
                       },
                   ]}}

 
   export class Books {
   render() {
       return (
          <View>
             <div>{data.book.name}</div>
          </View>
         );
      }
    }
```

Comment: “the book” is an invalid tag name. how are you adding this component to the page? any errors in the console?

Comment: Edited the question, I don't need the tag. With the given object named 'data' I want to render the book name

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by not needing the tag? Every web component needs a tag name which needs to contain a dash. Or do you mean it's not relevant? There's nothing really wrong with the code, here's a link with a working example: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/U90pTnVHXsKj2efKVfVD/src/index.tsx. Just looking at the tags, is your actual problem not that it doesn't render but that it doesn't render in reactive native?

Answer (score 0):

**div** should not be used in react-native, just replace it with **Text** after importing it. Secondly, class-based components should **extend React.Component** like so

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
const data = {
  book: {
    id: '2d320',
    name: 'book 1',
    Chapters: [
      {
        No: '1',
        date: '2010-04-22',
        plots: [
          {
            name: 'Hero',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        No: '2',
        date: '2010-04-22',
        plots: [
          {
            name: 'Heroine',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

class Book extends Component {
  render() {
    return <View>
             <Text>{data.book.name}</Text>
          </View>;
  }
}

export default Book;
```

Here is a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@subhayu/your-cat) displaying the output you want.

If you don't want to import Component from 'react' and like to export directly then may also use this syntax

```
export default class Book extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{data.book.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sarah if it works for you please accept the answer and if not happy to troubleshoot.